# Are there unicorns in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In which HP movie is something looking like an unicorn?

Are they really unicorns, or does it have another name ?

Comment: I don't understand the first part of the question. Are you asking in which HP movie is something looking like the unicorn?

Comment: thanks @TGar, I have simplified the question

Comment: That is actually really [easy to find](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Unicorn).

Comment: This question keeps on getting downvote. I cannot delete it. I don't want any downvote. It feels bad :( help

Comment: So much negative votes (which I agree about), but the question has *more than 1000 views* and is only a year old! It seems many people don't know much about Harry Poter, like me, after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

The first time we see mention of unicorns in the *Harry Potter* series is when Harry is looking at unicorn horns for sale:

> Hagrid wouldn't let Harry buy a solid gold cauldron, either ("It says
> pewter on yer list"), but they got a nice set of scales for weighing
> potion ingredients and a collapsible brass telescope. Then they visited
> the Apothecary, which was fascinating enough to make up for its horrible
> smell, a mixture of bad eggs and rotted cabbages. Barrels of slimy stuff
> stood on the floor; jars of herbs, dried roots, and bright powders lined
> the walls; bundles of feathers, strings of fangs, and snarled claws hung
> from the ceiling. While Hagrid asked the man behind the counter for a
> supply of some basic potion ingredients for Harry, Harry himself
> examined silver unicorn horns at twenty-one Galleons each and minuscule,
> glittery-black beetle eyes (five Knuts a scoop).
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer/Philosopher's Stone*, chapter 5: "Diagon Alley"</sub>

And then... spoiler for the first installment, since you don't seem to have read/watched it:

> Harry has to go with Hagrid to find a hurt unicorn in the forest, which turns out to have been killed by Voldemort drinking its blood.

> "Look there," said Hagrid, "see that stuff shinin' on the ground?
> Silvery stuff? That's unicorn blood. There's a unicorn in there bin hurt badly by summat. This is the second time in a week. I found one dead last Wednesday. We're gonna try an' find the poor thing. We might have ter put it out of its misery."
> "And what if whatever hurt the unicorn finds us first?" said Malfoy, unable to keep the fear out of his voice.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer/Philosopher's Stone*, chapter 15: "The Forbidden Forest"</sub>

And since you're asking about the movie, here's a screenshot of the unicorn mentioned above from the first *Harry Potter* movie:

> [image: dead unicorn with Quirrell drinking its blood]

Answer (score 1):

Harry sees a dead Unicorn in the first movie when he visits the forbidden forest as punishment.

> [image: dead unicorn]